# communicate c++ and java over native

Tags: java, java-native-interface, native-code

I want a simple example for a communicate of CPP code with Java through JNI.
As I am unable to find any good example to run & test it and learn JNI. Although I am new to JNI, but I have a knowledge of Java.

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you want to call c++ from java or other way around?

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jni/spec/jniTOC.html) is one of the most popular and reliable resource about the JNI interface, examples start from chapter 2.

Answer (score 1):

This is good tutorial for JNI from where I have learned as a beginner

http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/jni/getting_started.shtml

**OR**

As an beginner you can also start with SWIG

SWIG is a software development tool that connects programs written in C and C++ with a variety of high-level programming languages.

In a nutshell, SWIG is a compiler that takes C declarations and creates the wrappers needed to access those declarations from other languages including including Perl, Python, Tcl, Ruby, Guile, and Java

http://www.swig.org/